# List running local Shiny apps (and their port) from another R session

Tags: r, shiny

Assume I am running a Shiny app **locally** (I am not talking about Shiny server here), e.g.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

which give the following output

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3273
```

In addition, `http://127.0.0.1:3273` was automatically opened in a new tab in my web browser.

Assume I accidentally close my web browser, and I don't have a simple access to the window where `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3273` was printed (e.g. it is hidden, because run from an R script called from another script with some shady output redirection, or it is run from a container).

**Problem:** I do not know how to reopen my local Shiny app in my web browser because I do not remember which port it was using.

**Questions:**

- Is there a simple way to know that a local Shiny app is running on port `3273` from another R session?
- More generally, is there a way to list running local Shiny apps from another R session?

**Note:** I am trying to do that from R (eventually by using a specific R package) and without calling external system commands.

**Edit:** I know that if I close and reopen the app tag, it will be "reset" but it is not an issue.

Comment: Which Operating system are you using?

Comment: In the current setting, I am running the app inside a Linux subsystem on Windows (thanks to WSL). The broswer is opened on the host system (i.e. Windows), and I want to find a way to help the user reconnect if the browser tab is lost (and I do not want to hard-code the port used by Shiny).

Comment: `system("netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN  | grep /R")`

Comment: Many thanks @danlooo but I was wondering if I could find a way (using the Shiny package or another) to do that from R without calling any external system command.

Comment: You want to access data from other R processes. This is a job of the OS itself. Thus you use system tools here. I presented an R function to allow shell commands.

Comment: I thought about the `system` R function but I was hoping I could do that in full R, potentially by using a specific package (like `jupyter` is able to list all running local instances of `jupyter` on the machine). So I guess the answer to my question is just that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, open TCP ports are managed by the OS so you can use system shell commands e.g. `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN  | grep /R`.
However, you can create an R function downloading HTML and detecting shiny specific text in it (here: the presence of the file `shiny.min.css`):

Let there be a shiny app running on the same host at port 3775:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

is_running_shiny <- function(port) {
  tryCatch(
    str_glue("http://127.0.0.1:{port}") %>%
      GET() %>%
      content() %>%
      as.character() %>%
      str_detect("shiny\\.min\\.css"), 
    error = function(e) FALSE
  )
}

is_running_shiny(800)
# FALSE
is_running_shiny(3775)
# TRUE
```

However, you need to run this function for every port of the totaling 65535.
Only the OS knows the list right away.